# Namespace nesting for a devise user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, namespaces

I want this path, I thought I could do namespace with devise but cant figure it out so how can I accomplish this?

users/:user_id/bills/:bills_id

I have the following routes setup for a user.

```
#User routes
  devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "users/registrations", sessions: "users/sessions" }

  get "/users/LeastDefender_dashboard" => "users/dashboard#index", as: :users_main
  get "/users/why_choose_LeastDefender" => "users/landing#index", as: :users_why

  namespace :users do
    resources :landing, only: [:index, :show]
    resources :bills
    resources :dashboard
    get 'landing', to: 'landing#index'
    get 'dashboard', to: 'dashboard#index'
  end
```

How can I accomplish this?

users/:user_id/bills/:bills_id

When I rake routes I get this:

```
users_bills        GET    /users/bills(.:format)                  
users/bills#index  POST   /users/bills(.:format)                  users/bills#create
new_users_bill     GET    /users/bills/new(.:format)              users/bills#new
edit_users_bill    GET    /users/bills/:id/edit(.:format)         users/bills#edit
users_bill         GET    /users/bills/:id(.:format)              users/bills#show
                   PATCH  /users/bills/:id(.:format)              users/bills#update
                   PUT    /users/bills/:id(.:format)              users/bills#update
                   DELETE /users/bills/:id(.:format)              users/bills#destroy
```

Comment: or can i get this for the same effect /users/bills/:id I need the bills info to be specific to each user so when I do an index it only shows that users bills. DO i already have that or do I need to specify the user? Im confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
devise_for :users ...

resources :users do
  member do
    resources :bills
  end
end
```

It gives the following routes:

```
                                  bills GET    /users/:id/bills(.:format)                                             bills#index
                                        POST   /users/:id/bills(.:format)                                             bills#create
                               new_bill GET    /users/:id/bills/new(.:format)                                         bills#new
                              edit_bill GET    /users/:id/bills/:id/edit(.:format)                                    bills#edit
                                   bill GET    /users/:id/bills/:id(.:format)                                         bills#show
                                        PATCH  /users/:id/bills/:id(.:format)                                         bills#update
                                        PUT    /users/:id/bills/:id(.:format)                                         bills#update
                                        DELETE /users/:id/bills/:id(.:format)                                         bills#destroy
```

More about member routes: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-member-routes

Comment: what about devise and the devise_for :users should that go in the namespace area?

Comment: `devise_for :users` usually goes above the resources definition if `users` are being managed as resources. I edited the answer to reflect that. Ref: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface